# Laravel - Sort entries from multiple tables with similar rows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, inner-join

I need to get the entries from 5 different tables with the same structure

```
   $test = DB::table('table1')
    ->Join('table2')
    ->Join('table3')
    ->Join('table4')
    ->Join('table5')
    ->get();

    return $test;
```

How can I realize that using Laravel?

The Structure from the tables:

- id
- title
- default_thumb
- video_id
- url
- views
- rating
- tags
- created_at
- updated_at

All 5 tables have the same structure!
A problem could be **id** because in every table there are entrys with the same id ... 1 in all, 2 in all, 3 in all, etc.

If I use CrossJoin there is a error (out of memory) but even if I had enough memory set i will get only the entrys from table5 because the entrys from table1 to table4 got overwrited while the id's in the different tables are the same.

```
    $test = DB::table('table1')
    ->Join('table2', 'table1.id', '=', 'table2.id')
```

This is strange too!
Table1 has 20 entrys with id 1 to 20, Table2 has 50 entrys with id 1 to 50.

If i do this, i will get only 20 results from table 2...

Comment: You're asking a question on a Q&A site. It's pretty clear that you "need help". No need to include that in your question.

Comment: Aside from questioning why you have 5 tables with the same structure, the SQL way to do this is using `UNION`

Comment: I would very much question why you have 5 tables with the same structure. You're running in to this issue because your database is poorly designed. I would suggest solving the issue of your database design as that is the root cause here - it will also prevent you from running in to more issues down the track.